# Nav Bar is turning a weird light blue when I segue to that screen

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

Nowhere in my code am I setting the color of the Navigation Bar to this gradient. So I am confused why this is happening, as shown by the image. Anybody seen this issue before?

[image: Nav Bar has a blue gradient]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationBar.opaque = NO;
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Set this property for your navigationBar